# Phonegap Build plugin not recognised, js not loading

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-build, aem

I've been tasked with learning how to build Phonegap Apps through AEM 6.0. So far i managed to create an empty starting point app and get some features fro the ootb geometrixx app back in.

Now i've been trying to add the phonegap camera plugin without success.
I've added the required line to our config.xml: 
`<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" version="0.3.2" />` 
and to our installPlugins js that's called as a before_platforms_add cordova hook.

I've checked CLI build and the contents of the apk we're getting from phonegap build and all the files that should be present are present. However I'm *still* getting `File Not Found` errors on the js files and a `Plugin Does Not Exist` Cordova error.

[screenshot link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nz8na906o5su3em/Screen%20Shot%202015-02-13%20at%2017.38.22%20copy%202.png?dl=0) for browser console & file structure of apk

Googling hasn't gotten me any real pointers so far, perhaps somebody here can help me out?

Answer (score 0):

After after even more searching and delving into the apk provided by Phonegap Build, a solution has turned up:

As it turns out, there was a **third** place where the loading of the `js` files was controlled, namely the `contentsync-file-list.js.jsp` file located in the splash page component.

Somehow, although the files were present in the phonegap builds and known to cordova, the list of a plugin's `js` files not being included in the `contentsync-file-list.js.jsp` prevents them from actually being loaded by the app.